# Vertx: Future result availability and coding patterns

Tags: vert.x

I have some issues with understanding Vertx asynchronous model and how `Future` behave...

In the startup code of my application, I check some conditions, like db access and other credentials, then I start several management verticles (config verticle, http admin verticle, etc) before starting the core of the application. The code has the following structure:

```
Vertx vertx = null;
Vertx.clusteredVertx(opts, ar -> {
  if(ar.failed()) {
     System.exit(-1);
  }
  else {
    vertx = ar.result();
    Future<Void> f1 = asyncStartupFunction_1(...);
    if(f1.failed()) {
      System.exit(-1);
    }
    else { // f1 succeeded
      Future<Void> f2 = asyncStartupFunction_2(...);
      if(f2.failed()) {
         System.exit(-1);
      }
      else {  // f2 succeeded
        ...
      } // f2 succeeded
    } // f1 succeeded
  } // vertx creation OK
```

`asyncStartupFunction_x` do some asynchronous work (query a db or deploy a verticle) and then they return the `Future` that represents the result of this work.

I would have thought that once I'm in a `else` block, the corresponding future has succeeded. Is it possible that the work has not finished yet and that the corresponding future has not yet completed ? And thus, because `fx.failed() == false` I get to the  `else` block while (in my understanding) I shouldn't?

What would be the right pattern ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`asyncStartupFunction_1` returns a `Future` and there is no guarantee the future is completed at this point.

Consequently `f1.failed()` has good chances not to give your a proper result. It's not a blocking call, and it may return `false` simply because the future is not completed yet.

What you need is [async coordination](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_async_coordination). Depending on your needs, you can either execute the async jobs in parallel or sequentially.

Comment: I remember I already read that some time ago but just could remember where when I asked the question... Thanks for your time.